# How do I display the user entry in a label on tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I stored the entry in a entry widget called nameeentry but how do I display the user's entry in a label? I tried to use the normal label syntax and add command = nameentry but it keeps saying nameentry is not defined in the error

```
nameentry = ttk.Entry(win,width= 40)
nameentry.pack()
#send text button
ttk.Button(win, text= "Send Text",width= 20).pack(pady=20)

#how to display user entry in a label after this??
nameentry.get()

#here I want to add some code that stores this nameentry in a label but its not working...
playernamelabel=Label(win,text=nameentry)

win.mainloop() #end of window main loop
```

Comment: WHAT user entry?  All of the code you show gets executed as your program starts up - the Entry widget isn't even visible yet, and it's certainly not possible for the user to have typed anything into it.  So exactly when do you want the Label to be updated?  If you want it to be continuously updated, character-by-character as the user types, that's actually easy - associate both the Entry and Label with the same StringVar, and the update will be automatic.  Anything else would require that you define some event that triggers the update - perhaps the click of a Button, or the Entry losing focus.

Comment: Yeah I have a send button in my code and want it possibly to display the user entry in a label when that button is clicked. How do I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want a label to contain exactly the same thing that is in an `Entry` widget, the simplest solution is to tie them together with the same `textvariable`. If they share the same `textvariable`, the two will always display the same data.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = tk.StringVar(root)

entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=var)
label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=var)

entry.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=8, pady=8)
label.pack(side="top", fill="x", padx=8, pady=8)

entry.insert(0, "Hello, world")

tk.mainloop()
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks I just associating my nameentry entry widget with the playername label using the same textvariable but the user entry doesn't show up when I run it.

Comment: Nevermind it just worked! Thanks so much for your help, I just forgot to insert the label.pack function!